# Python animated multisubplot matplotlib won't show

Tags: python, variables, matplotlib, animation, plot

I'm trying to do an animated multisubplot view of function deformations with changing variables both in cartesian and polar. My code shows no error but won't output anything. Here it is:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as anim
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

X = np.arange(-10, 10.5, 0.6)
f = lambda x: x + 1/(x**2) + 3/2*np.sin(x)

g = lambda x, k: f(x + k)
h = lambda x, k: f(x) + k
i = lambda x, k: f(x * k)
j = lambda x, k: f(x) * k
l = lambda x, k: np.abs(f(x))
m = lambda x, k: k*f(k*(x+k))+k

funcs = [g, h, i, j, l]
names = ['f(x + k)', 'f(x) + k', 'f(k * x)', 'k * f(x)', '|f(x)|', 'YOLO']

f1, ax1 = plt.subplots(1, 6, figsize=(20,3))
#f2, ax2 = plt.subplots(1, 6, figsize=(20,3), subplot_kw=dict(projection='polar'))

for i, a in enumerate(ax1):
    a.set_title(names[i])

lines = []
for a in ax1:
    line, = a.plot(X, [np.nan] * len(X), 'g-')
    lines.append(line)

def animate1(k): # update the data.
    for l in lines:
        l.set_ydata(funcs[i](X, k))
    return lines[0]

ani = anim.FuncAnimation(f1, animate1, interval=2, blit=False, save_count=50)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I run your code I get an `IndexError: list index out of range` error on the line `l.set_ydata(funcs[i](X, k))` because your `funcs` array only has 5 elements in it, but it's looping over 6 elements because you have 6 subplots.  Try changing `funcs = [g, h, i, j, l]` to `funcs = [g, h, i, j, l, m]`

Edit:
After fixing that, it gives a `divide by zero` error on the same line.  This is because the first time through the `animate1` function, `k=0`.  So when you call the `m = lambda x, k: k*f(k*(x+k))+k` function, it passes a value of Zero to your `f = lambda x: x + 1/(x**2) + 3/2*np.sin(x)` and so it fails.  You'll need to address that somehow either in your lambda functions or in the `animate1` function.